# How to use Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, cisco-vpn-client

I wrote a [related question earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/235004/remote-desktop-connection-snow-leopard-to-windows-xp), which is still unresolved. This question is much more specific.

So I installed Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client on Snow Leopard. I connect to my work VPN. Once connected, I can't ping my work machine. I don't see any computers on the network. If the client were not running, I wouldn't believe myself to be connected to the VPN.

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Do I have to route my network traffic through the tunnel manually? (`ifconfig route` comes to mind) Is the POST request that I am about to submit going to go through the tunnel created by my VPN?

I guess the main question is: why do I feel so in the dark? Cisco says I am connected to my VPN, but for all I know it is invisible.

N.B. I do have the up-to-date Cisco VPN Client: version 2.3.2016. I installed it about a week ago.

Comment: do you have use gateway on remote network selected? common vpn problem.

Comment: If my work computer (Win XP) is asleep / on standby could that be causing the problem?

Comment: @aking: Thanks for your response. I don't know where to set this option. I looked in Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client preferences and there are only three options. (1) connect on startup (2) minimize to tray (3) enable local LAN access (if configured)

Comment: you could try disabling local LAN access...they might have changed the config screens - I only used a REALLY old one

Comment: Nope, no cigar. Hopefully I can fix it on the job tomorrow if I disable sleep and standby.

Comment: Yep. I fixed it by setting the power scheme to "Always On".

Answer (score 1):

When I use the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client to connect to my workplace, I need to use the FQDN to reach systems.  Plain old hostnames won't work.

For example, our intranet is on a system with the Windows hostname `in001`.  To reach it over the VPN, I have to enter `http://in001.corp.mycompany.net`

You also might try entering the internal IP address of any servers to possibly narrow it down to a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does you network security team impose any network restrictions on VPN users? For example, can they only access certain servers? Or do you have to register for access to destinations? You might want to reach out to the folks that manage your VPN. They can verify that you are connecting and verify you connectivity.